# Python Dataframe boxplot, wisker caluclation with outliers

Tags: python, dataframe, boxplot

I was curious at how pandas dataframe handles calculating the upper and lower whiskers, with outliers. Normally it's `1.5IQR-Q1, 1.5IQR+Q3`. However, the problem I can't understand, or maybe I'm wrong on how the whiskers are calculated. It shows the same problems in the boxplot section of https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html
Here's a sample of code I've randomly selected:

```
ray1=[0.217766,0.691315,0.289239,0.239135,0.161341,0.364297,0.373284,0.323216]
df = pd.DataFrame(ray1, dtype = float)
```

If I used the `df.describe()` it gives me the stats of that array.

```
count  8.000000
mean   0.332449
std    0.162374
min    0.161341
25%    0.233793
50%    0.306227
75%    0.366544
max    0.691315
```

But according to the upper whisker, lower whisker from the normal `1.5IQR-Q1, 1.5IQR+Q3`, it should be around `.565` and `.035`. If I plot this with `df.boxplot()` it shows the upper whisker as `0.373` and the lower whisker as `.161`. I've tried other variations (`2.698σ`) and the medcouple and those don't equal either.

So how is it getting those values, when outliers are present?

Comment: The `0.691315` value is an outlier. Do you consider that part of your distribution?

Comment: I guess I was assuming it was kept since it is an actual point. So are you saying it disregards the outliers when it calculates the whiskers?

Comment: yep. That's what it does

Comment: Is there a way to force it to stay in there, or would I have to do everything manually then?

Answer (score 0):

The whiskers calculated for the plot fall on values within your data. As your data only has 8 values it can be easily visualised where the position of the whiskers is coming from.

The following code produces your boxplot and also overlies the data points on this.

```
df.boxplot()
plt.plot([1]*len(df),df[0],'x')
plt.show()
```

The plot produced:

[image: boxplot]

Hopefully it is clear enough to see that the upper whisker falls on a datapoint.

From the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html:
"the upper whisker will **extend to last datum** less than Q3 + whis*IQR"